# Image not getting displayed in Laravel DOMPDF (only in server)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

I'm doing an online certificate generation part in laravel using dompdf. It was working fine until the server was changed. Now the images are not getting displayed (background image of certificate template and profile pic of student). It shows an error 'Image not found or type unknown'. It works well in localhost. Error occurs only in server.

This is my controller:

```
public function certPdfGenerate()
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $apply_id=  input::get('id');
    $get_certificate_data = DB::Connection('mysql1')->table('tbl_apply_certificate')->where('apply_id',$apply_id)->first();
    $get_certificate_id1 = DB::Connection('mysql1')->table('tbl_apply_certificate')->select('apply_certificate_id')->where('apply_id',$apply_id)->get()->toArray();
    foreach ($get_certificate_id1 as $key) 
        {
            $get_certificate_id = $key->apply_certificate_id;
        }
    $filename = $get_certificate_id.'.pdf';
    DB::Connection('mysql1')->table('tbl_apply_certificate')
        ->where('apply_id', $apply_id)
        ->update(['apply_pdf' => $filename]);       
    $data1 = [$get_certificate_data];
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('students::htmlcertificate', array('data' =>$data1), [], ['format' => 'A4-L']);
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream($filename);
}
```

And this is my view page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Certificate View</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @page 
    {
        size: 21.87cm 30.69cm landscape;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
        margin-left:0;
        margin-right:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    #certbackground
    {
          background-image: url('https://example.com/backend/public/cer_template/certtemplate.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center;
          background-size: contain;
          z-index: -1;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="certbackground">
  @foreach ($data as $value)

  <h3 style="margin-top: 860px;margin-left: 1370px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{$value->apply_name}}</h3>

  <img style="height: 600px!important;margin-top: -18px;margin-left: 2880px;" src="{{ URL::asset('public/certif_pro_image/'.$value->apply_photo) }}" />

  <h3 style="top:-160px!important;margin-top:-500px!important;margin-left: 1370px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{$value->apply_course}}</h3>

  <h3 style="position:absolute;top:1310px!important;margin-left: 1930px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value->apply_start_date))}}</h3>

  <h3 style="position:absolute;top:1250px!important;margin-left: 2370px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value->apply_end_date))}}</h3>

  <h3 style="position:absolute;top:1410px!important;margin-left: 1580px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{$value->apply_grade}}</h3>

  <h3 style="position:absolute;top:1410px!important;margin-left: 2290px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{$value->apply_certificate_id}}</h3>

  <h3 style="position:absolute;top:1575px!important;margin-left: 1575px;font-weight: 600;font-size:60px;color: #333;">{{$value->apply_centre}}</h3>

  @endforeach
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Double check the certificate - are there any ssl errors if you load the image in your browser and inspect the certificate? Such errors can often stop pdf rendering from loading assets.

Comment: checked.. it works well in localhost. Problem occured only after we changed the server

Comment: @SreyaSRV James is asking you to test the images on your server, not on localhost.

Comment: tested. image is loading in browser. but It doesn't display in the pdf.

Comment: The image not displayed is the one referenced in the CSS? Have you enabled support for remote resources? Does Dompdf have read/write access to the temp directory?